# Flutter List view builder doesn't shrink when Keyboard appears

Tags: flutter, flutter-animation

I'm creating a chat feature in flutter but noticed this behavior on IOS that doesnt shrink the list so you can see the last sent message. How can I have the listview builder shrink to show the last message when the keyboard appears?

Note: This issue doesn't happen on Android

```
Scaffold(
      resizeToAvoidBottomInset: true,
    body: Stack(
       children: <Widget>[
         StreamBuilder(
        stream: _chats,
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          if (!snapshot.hasData) return Container();
          return snapshot.hasData
              ? GestureDetector(
            onPanDown: (_) {
              FocusScope.of(context).requestFocus(FocusNode());
            },
            child: ListView.builder(
                shrinkWrap: true,
                controller: _scrollController,
                padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 10, bottom: 100),
                itemCount: snapshot.data.docs.length,
                itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                  return MessageWidget(
                    tripId: widget.docId,
                    uid: snapshot.data.docs[index].data()["uid"],
                    messageId: snapshot.data.docs[index].id,
                    message: snapshot.data.docs[index].data()["message"],
                    sender: snapshot.data.docs[index].data()["senderName"],
                    sentByMe: widget.uid ==
                        snapshot.data.docs[index].data()["uid"],
                    mediaFileUrl:
                    snapshot.data.docs[index].data()["mediaFileUrl"],
                  );
                }),
          )
              : Container();
        },
          );
      ]
     )
    )
```

[image: Keyboard Opened]

[image: Keyboard Closed]

Comment: As I wrote this question I'm thinking that the Stack widget might be causing the issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can try the 'reverse' property from the ListView.builder.
Tell me if this example didn't fit your needs, can you share us your code ? (I didn't see why you use a Stack and what could be the issue around that).

```dart
class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          Expanded(
            child: Stack(
              children: <Widget>[
                StreamBuilder<dynamic>(
                  builder: (context, dynamic snapshot) {
                    return GestureDetector(
                      onPanDown: (_) {
                        FocusScope.of(context).unfocus();
                      },
                      child: ListView.builder(
                        reverse: true,
                        shrinkWrap: true,
                        itemCount: 100,
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 10, bottom: 10),
                        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                          return ListTile(title: Text(index.toString()));
                        },
                      ),
                    );
                  },
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
          Container(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8),
            color: Colors.black12,
            child: const TextField(),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Reverse fixed the issue! Seems like it fixes a lot of the scrolling behavior annoyances I was having. Just had to change my query to get the data correctly. Thanks for your help